# Function Reference of own module not shown in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a project (folder) in Visual Studio Code with the following structure

```
- parentDirectory
  - __init__.py
  - MyModule
    - SubModule1
      - file1.py ( containgin customFunc1)
  - currentFile.ipynb
```

In `file1.py` there is a function `customFunc1` containing a docstring with a description.

I am Importing the function in `currentFile.ipynb` with from `MyModule.SubModule1.file1 import *`.

If I now go into the `currentFile` and hover above the call for `customFunc1` I do not see the pop up with the docstring for `customFunc1`.

I can see the description correctly when I am in another .py file that imports the function and can use the function correctly in the jupyter notebook.
**I can neither see the description for build in python functionnor for
my custom function when in the ipynb file .**

How can I activate the display of the docstring while in the jupyter notebook.

> Additional Information:
>
> - Conda Environment with scipy, numpy etc.
> - Jupyter Server: local
> - IDE: Visual Studio Code 1.64.2 ( Windows 10 )
> - Extensions in VSC
>
>   - Juypter ( Microsoft )
>   - Jypter  Keymap ( Microsoft )
>   - Jupyter Notebook Renderes (Microsoft)
>   - Linter (Nando Vieira )
>   - Python (Microsoft)
>   - Python for VSCode ( Thoms Haakon Townsend)
>   - Visual Studio IntelliCode (Microsoft)
>   - ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue with help of this "https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5415" post.

**The solution**:

Install pylance in the addon section of VSC and reload the window.